# What length of finishing nail should I use?

Tags: bathroom, trim, nails

I just re-tiled my master bathroom and plan to put wood trim back up around the perimeter soon. How do I know what length of finishing nails to use?

I see 2" and 1.5" nails - does it really matter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you want enough length that there is sufficient nail in the stud to hold the trim on. The drywall is 1/2" thick, so if your trim is 1/2" thick, that would only leave you 1/2" in the stud, which is not enough. So I would suggest 2" nails for what you are doing.

Comment: Thanks for also including your thought process in making the decision. Always good to teach a man to fish...